# My question is about javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type while trying to get port?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

i would like to know why i have this exception in my client code.
i have a wsdl and the web service interface only and try to call a methode oh this web service.

here is my client code :

```
   URL url = new URL("file:/C:/Projects/wsdl2.wsdl");
   QName qname = new QName("http://impl.service.proxy.ma/", "SPWSImplService");
   Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
   SPIntWS sPIntWS = service.getPort(SPIntWS.class);
```

i saw many cases like mine but in my case i cant give endpointIneterface in @WebService annotation in the implementation class.
Here is some logs :

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type: {http://ws.client/}SPIntWS
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:349)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:355)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:188)
at scci.client.application.Client.sPIntWSProcess(Client.java:74)
at scci.client.application.Client.main(Client.java:44)
```

Thnx for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In URL you were mentioning file path not host so you change this to

```
URL url = new URL("file:/C:/Projects/wsdl2.wsdl");
```

to be

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Projects/wsdl2.wsdl");
```

place your wsdl file under your workplace folder.

Comment: when i change it as you said i got connection time out, i think that the problem doesn't come from this point.

Comment: Yes, You should define the service end point interface (SEI) first.SEI typically is a standard Java interface. This is going to be the “wsdl:portType “ element in your WSDL document. The methods defined in SEI will become the “wsdl:operation” elements in the “wsdl:portType element” in WSDL. You need to annotate the SEI interface with required JAX-WS annotations.

Comment: You can use wsimport tool to generate the java classes from WSDL document.

Comment: You are using Top-down approach: Start with WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

to solve this error i used wsimport tool and generate both Interface and Implementation without changing anything in my client code.